# Node.js dates comparison

Tags: node.js, date

In Node.js, how do I compare the date with today's date if one of the dates is a string?

```
var retdate = new Date();
retdate.setDate(retdate.getDate()-7);
var mydate = '2016-07-26T09:29:05.000Z'
```

How do I compare 'retdate' and 'mydate' so it returns date older than 7 days? I believe the string needs to be modified?

Comment: use moment js module
http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by `so it returns date older than 7 days?`

Comment: as you can see he subtracted by 7 the retdate so he means if want to know if retdate is 7 days older than mydate sorry for too much edit

Answer (score 10):

**Updated solution:**

Since OP is asking for a solution that is based on standard Javascript API.

What you could do is, since your date string is compliance to the ISO-8601 date format, you can create the `Date` object through passing the date string to the constructor.

Once you got 2 `Date` objects you can directly subtract from objects giving you the `epoch` datetime. So using that, you just need to dividend it by the total number of milliseconds in a week (7 days) to figure out whether Date A is older than Date B or not.

**Example:**

```js
var retdate = new Date();
retdate.setDate(retdate.getDate()-7);
var mydatestring = '2016-07-26T09:29:05.00';
var mydate = new Date(mydatestring);

var difference = retdate - mydate; // difference in milliseconds

const TOTAL_MILLISECONDS_IN_A_WEEK = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

if (Math.floor(difference / TOTAL_MILLISECONDS_IN_A_WEEK) >= 7) {
    console.log("Current date is more than 7 days older than : " + mydatestring);
}
```

**MomentJS solution:**

Like 'Newbee Dev' said `MomentJS` is a good JS datetime module for solving all kinds of date related problems.

First parse your datetime string using the `moment(...)` constructor then use the `diff(...,'days')` API to do the day comparison.

**Example:**

```js
var datetime = '2016-07-26T09:29:05.000Z';
var localTime = moment();
var otherTime = moment(datetime);

console.log("Current datetime is older than " + datetime + " by 7 days = " + (localTime.diff(otherTime, 'days') >= 7));
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

**See**:
http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using AWS Lambda. Lambda doesnt allow importing modules. Is there a workaournd for my problem without using the modules?

Comment: Not familiar with AWS lambda but you should be able to push additional node modules into your NodeJS application. Have a read on this doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html

Comment: @tset just in case you couldn't get momentJS installed, I have updated my solution to include one that uses the standard Javascript API. Hope it helps, give me a shout if you have trouble with it.

Comment: const TOTAL_MILLISECONDS_IN_A_WEEK = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the date into milliseconds and do the math and convert it back to standard date.

```js
//Today's date
const today = new Date()
  //Six days before today
const sixDaysAgo = new Date(+(new Date()) - 6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  //Seven days before today
const sevenDaysAgo = new Date(+(new Date()) - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  //One year ago
const oneYearAgo = new Date(+(new Date()) - 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  //Given date from a date string
const givenDate = new Date("2016-07-26T09:29:05.000Z")

//Convert the range of days to milliseconds
//(This wont work if the date very old)
const sevenDaysInMiliSec = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

var dateToValidate = sevenDaysAgo;

if (today - dateToValidate >= sevenDaysInMiliSec) {
  console.log(dateToValidate + " is seven days older or more")
} else {
  console.log(dateToValidate + " is less than seven days old")
}

dateToValidate = sixDaysAgo;

if (today - dateToValidate >= sevenDaysInMiliSec) {
  console.log(dateToValidate + " is seven days older or more")
} else {
  console.log(dateToValidate + " is less than seven days old")
}

dateToValidate = oneYearAgo;

if (today - dateToValidate >= sevenDaysInMiliSec) {
  console.log(dateToValidate + " is seven days older or more")
} else {
  console.log(dateToValidate + " is less than seven days old")
}

dateToValidate = givenDate;

if (today - dateToValidate >= sevenDaysInMiliSec) {
  console.log(dateToValidate + " is seven days older or more")
} else {
  console.log(dateToValidate + " is less than seven days old")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use moment js just add this module into your dependencies

```
var moment = require('moment');

retdate = moment(retdate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
mydate = moment(mydate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am getting the error "Error: Cannot find module 'moment'". Any idea why?

Comment: add it in your node modules. install it

Comment: npm install moment

Comment: ok, I dont think that will work. I am using AWS Lambda. Not sure if you know about Lambda. I cannot install modules. Is there a workaournd for my problem without using modules?

Comment: you can install it and upload it to aws lambda too.

Comment: For this particular case moment seems like overkill.

Comment: Hi friends -- you should not add such a heavy dependancy for such a simple comparison.